# Maintain log files in Apache server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, logging

In my Java project I am using apache `log4j-1.2.17.jar` for storing logs in client side file  and manually  uploading these file Logs to server for future reference. I want to see these log file online in browser, so is there any apache library or inbuilt Servlet component which provide a UI to see these log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache Chainsaw to view log4j files.  http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/   It is a client UI.
If not, any one of the cloud logging services, loggly, Splunk, papertrail etc. can accept log4j files. Only thing is that they will cost.

Answer (score 0):

How about placing the log files in `/var/wwwroot/...` and make the `<Directory...>` browseable in the apache config (cf. `Options Indexes`)?

Cheers,